# Return ONLY one iteration of a pattern in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find and return a pattern (made up of numbers) in an array, but only return the pattern once.

```
ex. findPattern([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); 
should return [1];   not [1,1,1,1];

ex2. findPattern([1, 5, 4, 8, 7, 11, 10, 14, 13]); 
should return ([4, -1]);  not [ 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1, 4, -1 ];

ex3. findPattern([1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 1]); 
should return [ 4, -3, 1, -2, ];   not [ 4, -3, 1, -2, 4, -3, 1, -2 ];
```

Any thoughts on how I could do this simply, with a `function findPattern(arr){}`?

Comment: What does your current `findPattern` function look like?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please, try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to remove duplicates from an array. You can leverage the `Set` class to make a function like so:

```
const unique = xs => [ ...new Set(xs) ];
```

Then to use:

```
unique(findPattern([ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])); // [ 1 ]
```

More information about `Set` is [available on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).